# When to use std::numeric_limits<double>::espsilon() instead of DBL_EPSILON

Tags: c++

I understood that std::numeric_limits::espsilon() and DBL_EPSILON should deliver the same value but are defined in different headers, limits, and cfloat. Which makes std::numeric_limits::espsilon() a c++ style way of writing and DBL_EPSILON the c style.

My question is if there is any benefit in using std::numeric_limits::espsilon() over DBL_EPSILON in c++ project? Aside from a clean c++ coding style. Or did I understand this completely wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here on this page https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits you can find tables of what are the C marco equivalents of the `std::numeric_limits`.

They are equivalents, so for any pair of `std::limits` function/constant and C macro you find in the table, they can be interchanged.

The big difference is in generic code:

```
template <typename T>
void foo() {
     std::cout << std::numeric_limits<T>::epsilon();
}
```

Doing the same with C macros would require to write much more code. Also any opportunity to not use a macro is a good one.

Answer (score 0):

One obvious advantage of using `std::numeric_limits<T>::epsilon` is generic function. Imagine if you write some function like an ***almost-equal***. This function should accept floating numbers of different precisions, including `double`, `float`, `long double`. Or maybe even integer types as well. To write this with the macro solution, you would have to write an overload for each of the floating point types:

```cpp
bool almost_equal(float a, float b, int k)
{
    return std::abs(a - b) <= FLT_EPSILON * std::abs(a + b) * k;
}

bool almost_equal(double a, double b, int k)
{
    return std::abs(a - b) <= DBL_EPSILON * std::abs(a + b) * k;
}

...
```

But with the `numeric_limits` template, you can simply write a single function for all of them:

```cpp
template<typename T>
bool almost_equal(T a, T b, int k)
{
    return std::abs(a - b) <= std::numeric_limits<T>::epsilon() * std::abs(a + b) * k;
}
```

Comment: this `precision_digits` (renamed to `k`) is used in strange way. For me it doesn't make seance. Imagine what will happen when comparing 1.000000000001e13 with 1e13.

Comment: @MarekR I was thinking about a term, but I can't recall what it was called, changed it to `k` instead.

Comment: name is unimportant, logic is wrong.

Comment: @MarekR Can't do math 3 in the morning :(

Answer (score 0):

First of all `DBL_EPSILON` is a C API so it is a good practice to use C++ specific API in C++ code. I know it is more typing, still it is a good practice. In my code when I need `epsilon` multiple times for single type, I just bind it to some `constexpr`.

More important thing this is a great tool when you write a template. For example:

```cpp
template<std::floating_point T>
bool fuzzyCompare(T a, T b)
{
    return std::fabs(a - b) <= 4 * std::max(std::fabs(a), std::fabs(b)) * std::numeric_limits<T>::espsilon();
}
```